# 31st of January is missing in my calendar

Tags: excel

As you can see in the screenshots the calendar is showing just 30 days of January and the day 31 is missing. when I try to add this day manually by adding a new column(AG) it works. but when i scroll to the next month which is February the column AG turns blank! and when I scroll back to January its again 30 days!
    [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Why do you keep asking same problem again? Just edit your old questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my calendar is not showing the 31st day of January in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523978/my-calendar-is-not-showing-the-31st-day-of-january-in-excel)

Comment: here is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6oRHD8KdbkyTFNiMlFLVlRWWjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @raiden007, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You hide `Columns("C:NI")` and unhide only 30 columns from **column C** to **column AF**.

`Range("B3").Value` equals to **1** and `Range("B3").Value * 31 - 29` equals to **2**.
Likewise, `Range("B3").Value * 31 + 1` equals to **32**. So, you unhide only **30** columns **(32-2)**!
Just change your VBA code `Range("B3").Value * 31 - 29` to `Range("B3").Value * 31 -28` and `Range("B3").Value * 31 + 1` to `Range("B3").Value * 31 + 2` :

```
Sub showcalendar()
   LeaveTracker.Columns("C:NJ").Hidden = True
   LeaveTracker.Range(Columns(Range("B3").Value * 31 - 28), Columns(Range("B3").Value * 31 + 2)).Hidden = False
End Sub
```

And one more thing, change all `Column()-1` to `Column()-2` in your excel formulaes. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1NFlIQTc3ZnJOYk0) is your repaired workbook. Check and tell me any your ideas.

Comment: I saw you have battled with this file for a long time))

Comment: LOL! yep! you're right. for a long time! ;) thanks again man!