# Excel - display only columns with specific month and year

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Need help!

I have put into row 6 in Excel dates starting from 1st November, 2016 (Cell F6) to 31st December, 2017 (Cell PO6).
Cell B1 shows drop down list of months and cell B2 shows years.

I need a tip on how to set formula which will allow me to show only columns of month and year which are chosen in cells B1 and B2. For Example, if i choose November 2016, only columns F:AI will be visible, while columns AJ:PO will be hidden.

Please provide suggestions on how can this formula be formatted in different way, if you have suggestions.

Comment: Hiding columns is done through VBA, not by formula. Perhaps you should rephrase your question to make it clear.

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629523/31st-of-january-is-missing-in-my-calendar/40633531#40633531

Comment: @bzimor yeah, that is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write a VBA code combining if...then with

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Hidden = True
```

The if...then guide [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/752y8abs.aspx) and the hide column guide [is here](http://Worksheets(%22Sheet1%22).Columns(%22C%22).Hidden%20=%20True).